# Codeigniter hide URL segments

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting

I am new to codeigniter, is it possible to hide some segments in URL but need them inside controller, I know this might be a stupid question but for SEO I need to know.

My current URL:

> http://mysite.com/mobiles/smartphone/iphone-5/1534

Now here `mobiles` is my controller, `smartphone` is my function within `mobiles controller`, `iphone-5`  is the product name(just for SEO purpose) and the last `1534` is the ID which I need for SQL query

Is it possible to get this kind of URL

> http://mysite.com/mobiles/smartphone/iphone-5/

Here the main ID is not present in URL but in controller when I do `$this->uri->segment(4)` can I get that ID.

In simple words I just want to hide the ID from URL for SEO

Comment: What if you make the url like `iphone-5---1534` in your controller just explode by `---`

Comment: that makes a bad URL for SEO, I just want I PHONE 5 on url with class name and function name

Comment: I think but i am not sure that this requirement cannot be achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, you cannot do this, because codeigniter reads segments from browser URI. For such cases there is alias/slug. It is uniquely identification of each posts by aliasing/slugging title of the post e.g. The New Iphone 6 Released = the-new-iphone-6-released etc.